# How can I fix my recursive (divide and conquer) max subarray function?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I've looked over this code time and time again, compared it to other examples online and I can't seem to find where I've gone wrong with this. It's a divide and conquer, recursive approach to the max subarrary problem. Perhaps it's a small syntax error, perhaps it's something blatantly stupid, I just can't seem to fix it. I keep getting an error message saying *"RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"*. Any guidance or tips as to what I might be doing wrong? I'm brand new to Python, so anything is helpful and thank you for bearing with me.

```
    import math

def divConHelper(array, first, center, last):
  sumRight = 0
  sumLeft = 0

  # Determine crossover max toward left
  currentLTotal = 0
  for i in range(center, first, -1): 
    #Add values to sum one by one
    currentLTotal += array[i]
      #if the total is greater than the sumLeft, replace
    if currentLTotal > sumLeft:
      sumLeft = currentLTotal   
      leftIndexMax = i 

  # Determine crossover max toward right
  currentRTotal=0
  for j in range(center+1, last):
    #Incrementally add values to sum
    currentRTotal += array[j]
      #if the rightTotal is greater than the sumRight, replace
    if currentRTotal > sumRight:
      sumRight = currentRTotal
      rightIndexMax = j 

  bothTotal = rightTotal+leftTotal

  return(leftIndexMax, rightIndexMax, bothTotal)
  #return(bothTotal)

def divConMaxSub(array, first, last):

  first = 0
  last = len(array)-1

  # If no values in the file
  if len(array) == 0: 
    print("No values in file")
    return

  # If only one value in the file
  elif len(array) == 1:
    print("Only one value in file")
    return array[0]

  # If more than 1 value in the file... 
  else: 
    # Find middle value index by halving the last index
    center = math.floor((first+last)/2)
    # Make recursive calls inside max() function, including crossovers 
    # to find the max subarray & return the result

    return max(divConMaxSub(array, first, center), divConMaxSub(array, center+1, last), divConHelper(array, first, center, last))

#for test purposes    
arrayin = [1, 2, 4, -1, 4, -10]
maxsum= divConMaxSub(arrayin, 0, len(arrayin)-1)
```

Comment: why do you override your parameters? `first = 0
  last = len(array)-1`

Comment: What's the smallest data it doesn't work for? Does it work with any data?

Comment: You only break out if your data is of length zero or one. Otherwise you call the function again. You never reduce the size of the data in the recursion.

Comment: then there are other issues. you always work on the same array, so the length is always the same, but you only break the recursion on 0 or 1. for any array of len > 1, you never break. You need to test on `last - first` instead of `len(array)`

Comment: then you need to range up to `first -1`, you need to return only bothTotal, which should be `sumLeft + sumRight` instead of those undefined variables. finally, your initial call needs to go to `len(array)` instead of `len(array) - 1`, because ranges are [include, exclude).

Comment: and your 2 prints are misleading, remove then, and return 0 for len == 0

Comment: if you do all that, it should output 10, as expected.

Comment: These comments are all very helpful. I'm just confused on the range up to first -1 part, am I not doing that with "for i in range(center, first, -1)" ? Thank you very much again for your help.